# Removing color gradient window from Qt5 ColorDialog

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

This is the standard `Color Dialog` box from `Qt5`

[image]

Is it possible to view the basic colors alone and remove the color gradient from the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I found simple solution of this problem. It is not a removing, but with my code, we cannot see this gradient and cannot use it.

We need create subclass. Let's code:

mycolordialog.h

```
#ifndef MYCOLORDIALOG_H
#define MYCOLORDIALOG_H

#include <QColorDialog>
#include <QLabel>

class MyColorDialog : public QColorDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyColorDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:


};

#endif // MYCOLORDIALOG_H
```

mycolordialog.cpp

```
#include "mycolordialog.h"

MyColorDialog::MyColorDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QColorDialog(parent)
{
    QLabel * l = new QLabel("Teeeeext",this);
    l->setGeometry(245,5,325,215);//this values control the area and position of label
    //you can change this values and remove another area of main dialog window

    QPixmap pixmap("G:/2/qt.jpg");
    l->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(325,215,Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio));;//resize our picture
    l->show();
}
```

How to use it???

```
#include "mycolordialog.h"
//...
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_16_clicked()
{
    MyColorDialog cd;
    cd.exec();
    qDebug() << cd.selectedColor();
}
```

You can set in label  beautiful logo of your app, or something another. I use logo from here http://reichertbrothers.com/images/qt-logo.png , but I convert it into jpg format.

What we get???

[image]

Notice, that all another area is available and you can choose any color and work as you want, but this gradient window is remove!!

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The options that you can select to modify the look of the color dialog are in the [QColorDialog](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qcolordialog.html#options-prop) documentation.

```
    enum ColorDialogOption {
    ShowAlphaChannel    = 0x00000001,
    NoButtons           = 0x00000002,
    DontUseNativeDialog = 0x00000004
    };
```

This options do not hide the color picker, therefore you will have to implement your custom color picker.